# for loop always returning output 4444 instead of 1111 in php

Tags: php, mysql

```
 for($i =0; $i <$firstCounter; $i++) {
     //echo  $firstResultArray[$i]['Startdatetime'];
            $query1 = "select p.PlaceID,p.PlaceName AS placeName,p.Location,p.Address AS placeAddress,p.Latitude,p.Longitude,p.StarRating AS placeRating,d.DealNO,d.DealTitle,d.MinPersons,d.MaxPersons,d.Price AS dealPrice,d.TypeofDeal,d.url AS placeImg,d.priceRange,
            d.PlaceID,t.StartDay,t.EndDay,t.DealNO,t.Startdatetime,t.Enddatetime
            from places p
                        INNER JOIN dealdetails d ON p.PlaceID = d.PlaceID
                        INNER JOIN dealtime t
                        ON t.DealNO = d.DealNO 
                        WHERE 
                        d.TypeofDeal='".$BusinessType."' and d.MinPersons BETWEEN 1 AND 3 and  '".$firstResultArray[$i]['Startdatetime']."' <= '" .$datetime."' and  '".$firstResultArray[$i]['Enddatetime']."' > '" .$datetime ."' 
                        ORDER BY placeDistance";


            $result1 = mysql_query($query1);
             //echo "result: "+ $result;

            $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result1);
    echo $num_rows;



        }
```

echo numrows always returning 4 instead of one. the output is 4444. dont knw why? can anybody help plz?

Comment: Thats some strange piece of "code"

Comment: you should post your op correctly.

Comment: in your query ->`LIMIT 1`

Answer (score 1):

`mysql_num_rows()` always returns the count of rows found. the query must be returning `4` thats why it is printing `4444`.

You should not use `mysql` as it is deprecated in the newer varsions. Use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead.

Comment: But the query is according to  basic  MySQL. what is depreciated in this query? Can you explain please?

Comment: `mysql` will not be present in future `PHP` version. so start using `mysqli` or `Pdo`

Comment: But now i am just concerning about this query not about future. can u tell about this?